# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in c:/.../list.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I am a beginner who is studying programming hard. SyntaxError: missing) after argument list in c://.../list.ejs while compiling ejs error but I don't know the solution. I want to get help from someone who is good at programming. Please help me.

This is server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
const fs = require('fs');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  }));

app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log('서버가 실행됩니다.');
  });

// maria db와 연결, test
const db = require('./db');
const { result } = require('lodash');
const { setEngine } = require('crypto');
db.query('SELECT now() AS time', function(err, rows, fields) {
     if (err) throw err;
       console.log('The time is: ', rows[0].time);
    
  });
db.end();

// ejs를 통해서 html을 불러오는데 css까지 같이 불러옴
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//app.set('views', './crud/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);


// 정적 파일 서비스
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('views'));

// html 파일을 불러오는 작업
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('list.ejs');
   }); 

   
// 게시판에 사용자가 작성한 데이터를 db와 통신
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('list.ejs', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    db.query('select * from user', function (err, results) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err)
      } else {
        res.send(ejs.render(data, {
          data: results
        }))
      }
    })
  })
})

app.get('/delete/:id', function (req, res) {
    db.query('delete from user where id=?', [req.params.id], function () {
      res.redirect('/')
    })
  })

  app.get('/write', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('write.html', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      res.send(data)
    })
  })

  app.post('/write', function (req, res) {
    const body = req.body
  
    db.query('insert into user (title, name, content) values (?, ?, ?);', [
        body.title,
        body.name,
        body.date,
        body.howmanyseen,
        body.content
        ], function() {
        res.redirect('/')
    });
  });

  app.get('/edit/:id', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('edit.ejs', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      db.query('select * from user where id = ?', [req.params.id], function (err, result) {
        res.send(ejs.render(data, {
          data: result[0]
        }))
      })
    })
  })
  app.post('/edit/:id', function (req, res) {
    const body = req.body
  
    db.query('update user SET title=?, name=?, content=? where id=?',[
      body.title, body.name, body.content, req.params.id
    ], function () {
      res.redirect('/')
    })
  })
```

This is db.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host :'localhost',
    user :'root',
    password :'password',
    database :'express_db'
});
db.connect();
module.exports = db;`
```

This is list.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>공지사항</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/css.css">
</head>
<body>
    <% data.forEach(function (item, index) { %>
    <div class="board_wrap">
        <div class="board_title">
            <strong>게시판</strong>
            <p>예쁜놈으로다가 하나 긁어왔습니다!</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="board_list_wrap">
            <div class="board_list">
                <div class="top">
                    <div class="num">번호</div>
                    <div class="title">제목</div>
                    <div class="writer">글쓴이</div>
                    <div class="date">작성일</div>
                    <div class="count">조회</div>
                    <div class="delete">삭제</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="num"><%= item.id %></div>
                    <div class="title"><a href="view.html"></a><%= item.title %></div>
                    <div class="writer"><%= item.name %></div>
                    <div class="date"><%= item.date %></div>
                    <div class="count"><%= item.howmanyseen %></div>
                    <a href="/delete/<%= item.id%>">DELETE</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        



            <div class="board_page">
                <a href="#" class="bt first"><<</a>
                <a href="#" class="bt prev"><</a>
                <a href="#" class="num on">1</a>
                <a href="#" class="num">2</a>
                <a href="#" class="num">3</a>
                <a href="#" class="num">4</a>
                <a href="#" class="num">5</a>
                <a href="#" class="bt next">></a>
                <a href="#" class="bt last">>></a>
            </div>
            <div class="bt_wrap">
                
                <a href="/write.html" class="on">등록</a>
                <!--<a href="#">수정</a>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% }); %> 
</body>
</html>
```

I googled, but I couldn't find the right cause for this error because I saw different posts.
We are making a bulletin board through various trials and errors, and the goal is to have the bulletin board appear through the server and save it in the db once you enter the data.

Answer (score 0):

perharps you have a title in your database that has a "(" character ?
by the way the line  <%= item.title %>   seems strange. Are you sure you want an hyperlink on view.html with empty text ?

be careful, you need to escape special characters in html (or xml ).